# Depend drop down list in google sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Im working with google sheets.
In list 1 i have some data, which are copied to list 2 by

```
=query(A1:B1000;"select A order by A")
```

In list 2 i have drop down list with static answers "yes, no, etc" and i need to choose answer for every data from list 1

For example:

2. Yes
3. No
4. No

Problem is when im add some data like "1" its will be sorted to start of column and i have:

1. Yes
2. No
3. No
4. 

Is it possible somehow to link drop down list to each data, so if data move upper or lower, answer will move also?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1epf7ofrKFYTcKKC-eBtEjx9ogsmsd8f8lydOhdVMtbc/edit#gid=1867361376

Comment: Could you include a link to the spreadsheet so it is easier to see and understand the issue?

Comment: google-apps-scripts is not related to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can order it by row:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({ROW(base!A2:A100)\ base!A2:D100}; 
 "select Col4,Col5 where Col5 is not null order by Col1"; 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thx, its work but not exactly how i want. Column A is some time range and i want to sort by this time, also i want to save answers. Your example add every new data in the end, but its dont sorted by time. For example if i have 10:55 and 10:56 results with answers already, and if im add 10:01, i want this to be added before 10:55 in the test table and to save current answers for 10:55 and 10:56.  With my example if i add 10:01 other data will jump lower for 1 cell, but answers will be on same places. Is it possible to link answers somehow to the data?

Comment: @Andrew what you describe in your comment is possible to achieve only via script

Comment: @player0 can you help me with this by some example, please?

Comment: @Andrew something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UGGv.png which will sort the whole range in blocks of rows.

Comment: @player0 yes, its works, but only with all data what i fill by hands. im use =query to get all data and fill by hands only drop down list, but with query function this script is broken when im add new data in source and dont work( any idea how to merge =query and this script? Like get all data by script, not =query or smthng else? Thx for help!